# Django Model filters method finder

Tags: python, django

I would like to know if there is any way to do dynamically regroup a model by all available columns.

**models.py**

```
class ProductionPlan(models.Model):
    status_choices = (
        ('READY TO START', 'Ready To Start'),
        ('IN PROGRESS', 'In Progress'),
        ('PROGRESS STOPPED', 'Progress Stopped'),
        ('MAINTENANCE STOPPED', 'Maintenance Stopped'),
        ('QUALITY STOPPED', 'Quality Stopped'),
    )
    id = models.CharField(max_length=15, primary_key=True)
    first_start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    bills_of_material = models.ForeignKey(BillsOfMaterial, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    scheduled_date = models.DateTimeField()
    real_duration = models.DurationField()
    expected_duration = models.DurationField(default=None)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Ready To Start', choices=status_choices)
```

now if i want to filter model i would use `ProductionPlan.objects.filter(status__icontains = '')`

Then my question is  this method of searching **status__icontains** or any other (**start_date_contains**, **expected_duration__startswith**) how can i get these methods.

my end point is something like this:

```
def get_methods_for_filter(model):
    do something here
    return ((**start_date_contains**, **expected_duration__startswith**)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking or what you mean by dynamically regrouping a model. Are you looking to return all possible keywords that can be passed to a filter - a list of strings like `'status__exact', 'status__iexact', 'status__contains', 'status__icontains', ...` but for all fields?

Comment: @IainShelvington just curious, if yes how can we do that?

Comment: @ilyasbbu model fields have a `get_lookups` method that will return all valid lookups for that field, you can access the field from the meta API - `ProductionPlan._meta.get_field('status').get_lookups()` should return a dictionary where the keys are the lookup that would come after the double underscore like `{'exact': <class 'django.db.models.lookups.Exact'>, 'iexact': <class 'django.db.models.lookups.IExact'>, ...}`

Comment: @IainShelvington yes exactly what i want is of list all possible kwargs but the one can be used not string type?

Comment: So after **get_lookup** how can  I filter with it ?

Comment: Thanks everyone  i found a solution:                                                                                               your_filters = {
'field_1__exact': value_1,
'field_2__gte': value_2,
}

Model.objects.filter(**your_filters)